# Maven keeps reverting to jdk-8 even after setting JAVA_HOME to jdk-17

Tags: macos, maven, java-8, java-17, maven-compiler-plugin

When running `mvn clean install`, I keep running into errors of the form `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project test: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17`. When I completely delete my JDK 8 installation, it seems to work fine, but the moment I reinstall it (for some other project's dependency), I start seeing this error.

I use JEnv to set Global/Local JDK versions:

```
▶ jenv versions
  system
  1.8.0.372-internal
  17.0
  17.0.7
  openjdk64-1.8.0.372-internal
* oracle64-17.0.7 (set by /Users/vijay/.jenv/version)
```

and the global one points to JDK 17:

```
▶ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/vijay/.jenv/versions/oracle64-17.0.7

▶ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.2 (c9616018c7a021c1c39be70fb2843d6f5f9b8a1c)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.2/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_372-internal, vendor: OpenLogic-OpenJDK, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openlogic-openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.3.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Here's how I'm setting maven's jdk version in pom.xml:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
...
...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                ...
                <requireJavaVersion>
                  <version>17</version>
                </requireJavaVersion>
                ...
              </rules>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

How do I force maven to respect `$JAVA_HOME`?

I tried removing JDK 8 completely - which fixed the issue, but when using JEnv to switch the local JDK version of a particular project to JDK 8, and then using a different terminal window to set global/local JDK versions of this project to 17, maven starts reverting to JDK 8.

---

EDIT 1:
The following "workaround" works for me, but it's not ideal:

```
cd jdk-8-project
jenv local openjdk64-1.8.0.372-internal
mvn clean install
# Temporarily "uninstall" jdk 8
sudo mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openlogic-openjdk-8.jdk ~/Desktop/
cd jdk-17-project
jenv local 17.0.7
mvn clean install
# "Re-install" jdk 8
sudo mv ~/Desktop/openlogic-openjdk-8.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

Comment: `and then using a different terminal window to set global/local JDK versions of this project to 17, maven starts reverting to JDK 8.` you can only change the setting for the current window...or globally but not changing the setting for another window...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I've tried both options you mentioned (and every other permutation I could think of)... (a) setting global to 17, local to 8 (b) setting global to 8, local to 17 (c) setting 2 different locals in 2 different/same windows, etc.

But the only thing that worked was:
`cd jdk-8-project && jenv local openjdk64-1.8.0.372-internal && mvn clean install && sudo mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openlogic-openjdk-8.jdk ~/Desktop/ && cd jdk-17-project && jenv local 17.0.7 && mvn clean install`

Comment: You are running Maven inside Rosetta (x86 emulation). If the Java 17 installation is arm64 then it the Maven version might not be able to access it as it is from a different architecture.

Comment: @Robert, but maven is able to access java 17 if that's the only jdk installed - i.e., after I "remove" java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my mac. I resolved it by the following step (not sure if it applies to you)

`vim ~/.mavenrc`

and delete the line that

`export JAVA_HOME=my_location_of_jdk8`